# jquery remove new line then wrap textnodes with block element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some paragraphs like this:

> "This is the first para. r\r\n\n This
>   is the second one with lot of new line
>   after \n\n\n\n\n\n And the last para.
>   \n\r\r"

I want to remove the new lines and wrap each paragraph with the `<p>` tag. I'm expecting output as follows:

```
<p>This is the first para.</p>
<p>This is the second one with lot of new line after</p>
<p>And the last para.</p>
```

Comment: is this actually what you need or only an example? I mean will there be more line breaks etc... Anything that breaks the line should be converted into <p> or </p> ?

Comment: it's an example, there could be more or less line breaks. Anything that looks like a paragraph will be converted into <p></p>

Comment: \r and other control characters are to be ignored in HTML. They are valid in strings (if escaped)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var d = "line 1\n\nline2\n\n\n\nline3";
$('body').append('<p>'+d.replace(/[\r\n]+(?=[^\r\n])/g,'</p><p>')+'</p>');
```

something like this perhaps?

*If you find the line contains any new lines/carriage returns at the beginning or end, remember to call a `.trim()` on the string first before replacing the values (using this example, `d.trim().replace(...)`)*

**More robust solution**

```
function p(t){
    t = t.trim();
    return (t.length>0?'<p>'+t.replace(/[\r\n]+/,'</p><p>')+'</p>':null);
}
document.write(p('this is a paragraph\r\nThis is another paragraph'));
```

---

PHP Version:

```
$d = "paragraph 1\r\nparagraph 2\r\n\r\n\r\nparagraph3";
echo "<p>".preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/','</p><p>',$d)."</p>";
```

http://www.ideone.com/1TRhh

Comment: I think that wouldn't work correctly the the line brakes starts with `r\\`since it would take the first r as part of the text, am I correct?

Comment: @Trufa: The `[\r\n]` means either a new line or carriage return, the following `+` meaning repeated 1+ times. This would handle either order, any succession. (e.g. `\r` `\n` `\r\n\n` `\n\r\n\` etc.)

Comment: @Trufa: Why would it care? "r" is not a carriage return character, it's part of the string. What if the word ended in r, e.g. `harder\r\n\r\nfaster\r\nstronger`

Comment: @runrunforest and @Brad my bad to both, that was stupid of me! as brad explains my example is NOT valid since r\\ is not a carriage return character I got confused by the OP example since it displays `r\r\n\n` but that is actually a "typo" or a mistake, so brad and runrun, my bad! BTW @runrun do you agree this should be fixed?

Comment: What if `var d = ""` or `"\n\n\n"` ?

Comment: @sln: Thought about that, see updated answer. Also accounts for `"\r\nfoo"` and `"bar\r\n"`

Comment: @Brad - Even after its trimmed the variable has to be checked for length, otherwise "" turns into "<p></p>". Boundry conditions and trimming could all be done in a single regex `/(?:[\r\n]*)(.+)(?:[\r\n]*)/`

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var output = $();

$.each("This is the first para. \r\n\n This is the second one with lot of new line after \n\n\n\n\n\n And the last para. \n\r\r".split(/[\n\r]+/g), function(i, el) {
    if (el) {
        output = output.add($('<p>' + el + '</p>'));
    }
});
```

This creates a jQuery selection containing the `p` elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
function parse_it(yourstring, tagname){
   yourstring.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '#x#');
   paragraphs = yourstring.split('#x#');

   pars = "";
   for(var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++)
      pars += '<'+tagname+'>'+paragraphs[i]+'</'+tagname+'>';

   return pars;
}

var parsedstring = parse_it("This is the first para. r\r\n\n This is the second one with lot of new line after \n\n\n\n\n\n And the last para. \n\r\r", 'p');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace regex:  `/(?:[\r\n]*)(.+)(?:[\r\n]*)/`
with: `<p>$1</p>`
context: global

In Perl its: `s/ (?:[\r\n]*) (.+) (?:[\r\n]*) /<p>$1<\/p>/xg`